# What is a stochastic electromagnetic wave?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, quantum-optics, stochastic-processes

In statistical optics we always talking about stochastic electromagnetic wave but I am not able to understand how this wave is different from electromagnetic wave